# How to enable NULL values in MySQL timestamp fields?

Tags: mysql, backup, mariadb

I need to restore backup from one MariaDB server (version 10.1.23) to another MariaDB server (version 10.1.37). But this version has a much stricter mode by default and does not allow NULL values in timestamp fields and throws the below error when I restore the backup.

> 1067 - Invalid default value for 'dt'

I try to add this values to *.cnf file in /etc/mysql/conf.d/

```
[mysqld]

sql_mode=ALLOW_INVALID_DATES,IGNORE_SPACE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp=OFF
```

Queries:

```
show variables like 'sql_mode';
show variables like 'explicit_defaults_for_timestamp';
```

show changed values of variables but it does not work. Why?

Comment: Is the `dt` column allowed to be null in the DDL?

Comment: Yes, it allowed

Comment: Please show us the `CREATE TABLE` that has `dt`.  Also, what version of MariaDB/MySQL was the dump taken on?  And loaded onto?

Comment: `CREATE TABLE `check_login` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dt` timestamp DEFAULT NULL,
  `bookmaker` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uid_bk` (`uid`,`bookmaker`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;`

Comment: MariaDB 10.1.23 ==> MariaDB 10.1.37

Answer (score 4):

```
ALTER TABLE table_name 
  MODIFY dt TIMESTAMP NULL;
```

This will alter the table with name *table_name* to set the column *dt* to nullable.